# JSF / primefaces handling of control character (form feed hex: 0x0c) in ajax requests?

Tags: primefaces, escaping, jsf-2.2

I am curious about a edge case I have run across when using ajax requests in JSF / primefaces.

I found that if I input a form feed character ("/f" in java or 0x0C in hex) into a request that is handled via ajax it causes the ajax request to fail because the xml generated is considered invalid.  I would only expect this scenario to come up if a user is copying and pasting something from another document which happens to contain this character or more likely a QA person (or malicious user) input the character in an attempt to ruin my day.

Exact response I see in chrome developer tools:

```
<partial-responseid="j_id1">
  <parsererror>
    <h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3>
    <div>
      error on line 2 at column 68: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
      Bytes: 0x0C 0x20 0x63 0x61
    </div>
  <h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3>
  </parsererror>
  <changes>
    <update id="j_idt5"/>
  </changes>
</partial-response>
```

[Sample Project to reproduce the error](https://github.com/booya234/jsf-ajax-parseerror-on-formfeed)

There seems to be a limitation in XML that this character cannot be included in XML 1.0 so is there anything that JSF / primefaces can do to avoid this scenario or am I asking too much from the framework?  If I cannot get JSF / primefaces to handle this gracefully how can I make it so that a proper error page is generated and the issue is logged somewhere other then the users console?

Comment: let me investigate this and get back to you.  We have been doing a lot of proper escaping in PrimeFaces to handle characters i wonder if this example is a case that fell through the cracks or is a real problem.  I will report back.

Comment: I have definitely confirmed your error on PF 6.2.

Comment: Looks like it is a JSF/Mojarra bug. I updated my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it to be a bug and reported it here:  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3875

I will report back once the issue has been addressed.

**Update:** It turns out to be a Mojarra issue:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4516

Comment: Following the two issues you provided here it doesn't look like it is fixed in Mojarra. Am I missing something?

Comment: its not fixed in Mojarra but is fixed in MyFaces.  Mojarra dev has slowed for a while as they are transitioning from Oracle to Eclipse ownership.